# How should I start reverse engineering a website?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner web developer on my first reverse engineering attempt. I have to use HTML and CSS to clone a website.

I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start; should I write the entire page in HTML first and then proceed to CSS? Or should I do it by segment?

**Here's the site I'm trying to reverse engineer:**

> http://completewebdevelopercourse.com/clone/

Sorry if this has been asked before; but I can't seem to find a thread with an answer basic enough for me to comprehend at this point.

Comment: Your question is too wide

Comment: Perhaps you could download `(ctrl+s)` the page then modify the contents. This would be more effective & efficient & more accurate than re-creating the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the source code of a web page by right clicking on the page and selecting `View Source` so if there is anything you want to know about the HTML or CSS that is how to see it.

You can also use browser plugins like `Firebug` (for Firefox) to inspect the source.

However, I don't think you want to do that, unless you're stuck.

You can 'clone' the web page just by looking at it. The header section has some elements, the heading is centered, the text is black, there's an image here, and here and here. The body has a bunch of sections, and they have elements this, and that.

I would do HTML and CSS together, and just work on a part at a time. Get the main structure of the page done, and then work on the small stuff.

Comment: Got it. Thanks matt!